# passing values between a section template and an other section

Tags: templates, orbeon

i'm using Orbeon section templates in a common library that i use in multiple forms.

I need some values of a given section template to determine the visibility of some controls in other sections of my form. So i'm looking for a solution to parametrize the section template in order to never access its inner control values.

Can someone pls explain to me how to achieve that?

Comment: yeah i'm using Form Builder for creating the section template and the forms where to include the section template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To refer to the value of a field which is inside a section template from a field outside of that section template (and itself not in another section template), you can't use the `$field-name` syntax. You can from inside the section template, but not from outside the section template. This is because section templates really encapsulate their content, thus allowing you, for instance, to have multiple instances of the same section template in your form, or multiple section templates using the same field names.

So, to answer your question, this is a case where you need to use a path expression. Say the field you want to refer to is named `street` and you named that particular instance of the template `shipping`, then you can refer to the value of the field with the expression `/form/shipping/street`. If you add another instance of that same template, and name that instance `billing`, then you could refer to that other street field as `/form/billing/street`.

Comment: Ok, but considering the fact that a section template is a black box, and for code maintenance reason, we shouldn't access directly the controls in the section template. So is it possible to have a sort of interface for the section template that would never change even if we change the names of its controls?

Comment: @trin86 In this case, the interface is the name of the controls in the section. If you want to refer to a control in a section, you need to have some kind of name for it. I think you're suggesting that controls in reusable section could have two names: one which you use from the outside and one used for the element name. I am not sure that the added complexity would buy us much, and currently, there is just one name.