# Orbeon - Can I parameterize a Section Template?

Tags: orbeon

For example, I have a section template called "Full Name". It contains three fields:

1. First Name
2. Last Name
3. Middle Initial

On some forms, I want to display Middle Initial and on others I want that field hidden. I've created a form that includes that section template as well as a section called "Variables" which is always hidden. That section includes a field called "Show Middle Initial".

The form instance data looks like this:

```
<form>
    <variables>
        <showMiddleInitial>true</showMiddleInitial>
    </variables>
    <fullName>
        <firstName/>
        <lastName/>
        <middleName/>
    </fullName>
</form>
```

I added a Visibility expression to the middleName control in the section template:

`/form/variables/showMiddleInitial = 'true'`

This is similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9511681/3590534) but in reverse since the section template is accessing the parent form's data. I thought this might work since they are all using the same instance data but unfortunately it doesn't. If the control is in a section template then the `/form/variables/showMiddleInitial` expression always returns empty. If it's in the same form as the showMiddleInitial field then it returns the correct value `'true'`.

Am I doing something wrong? Or is there another way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following expression should work:

```
xxf:component-context()/root()/form/variables/showMiddleInitial = 'true'
```